# Creating a string with a repeating structure

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a string with the following output:

```
1: (a, b),
2: (b, c), 
3: (c, d), 
4: (d, e), 
5: (e, f), 
...
```

Where the letters are numbers.

There are a few factors I would like to be able to control:

- the start value 'a'
- the number of rows. Sometimes I'll need 5 rows, other times 20+
- the increment by which the values increase (a to b and b to c will increase by the same amount, but I would like the flexibility to change the increment value later on).

Based on previous feedback, I have the following code:

```
final_lst = []
for x in range(2390, 2640, 50):     # start, end, what it counts by 
    final_lst.append([x, x+50])
print(final_lst)

for i in range(1, 5):   # bin ranges 
    print('%s: (%s,%s),'%(i, x*1, (x+50)))
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three parameters:

1. Number of rows `N`
2. Starting number `START`
3. Interval size `DELTA`

You can basically use the code you have now, but with certain values replaced with your parameters.

```
from itertools import islice, count


START = 2390
DELTA = 50
N = 5

for i, x in islice(enumerate(count(START, DELTA), start=1), N):
   print(f'{i}: ({x}, {x + DELTA})')
```

- `count(START, DELTA)` produces an infinite sequence of values `START`, `START + DELTA`, `START + 2*DELTA`, ...
- `enumerate` pairs each element with a number 1, 2, 3, etc.
- `islice` yields only the first `N` elements of its iterator argument

Ideally, you wouldn't have to repeat the use of `DELTA` in two places. You could use `itertools.tee` and `zip`, but I don't think it's a marked improvement. There's no "inline" way to advance `stop` to prepare it to be zipped with `start`.

```
start, stop = tee(count(START, DELTA))
next(stop)

for i, (x, y) in islice(enumerate(zip(start, stop), start=1), N):
    print(f'{i}: ({x}, {y})')
```

Answer (score 0):

A few quick notes before addressing your question.

1. Since you want to be able to change a couple parameters (start, num rows, increment) this is a good task to frame as a function that takes these parameters as input.
2. You are using the old method of string formatting to express numbers as strings. It is generally frowned upon and you should instead use the new format: `"string {} {}".format(value,value2)`, which automatically places value at the first set of curly braces and value2 at the second, taking care of formatting more succinctly and cleanly.

   ```
   def create_list(start,n_iterations,increment):
       output = [] # to store final list

       # if only one argument is given in range, automatically starts range at 0 and increments by 1
       for i in range(n_iterations): 
           val1 = start + i*increment
           val2 = start + (i+1)*increment
           row = "{}: ({},{}),".format(i,val1,val2)
           output.append(row)

       #return completed list
       return output





   #call function
   my_list = create_list(0,10,100)

   # print list
   for row in my_list:
       print(row)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one liner to construct the string (not very readable obviously)

```
a = 10  # starting value
inc = 5  # increment
rows = 5 

s = ",\n".join("{}: ({}, {})".format(i+1, a+i*inc, a+(i+1)*inc) for i in range(rows))

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand, but from what I understand this should suffice:

```py
def rows(initial_value=0, nb_rows=5, row_increment=1):
    string = ""
    for index, value in enumerate(range(initial_value, nb_rows * row_increment, row_increment)):
        string += f"{index}: {(value, value + row_increment)},\n"
    return string
```

You can then call this and pass any parameter you need to:

```py
>>> print(rows(nb_rows=3))
0: (0, 1),
1: (1, 2),
2: (2, 3),
```

An even cleaner solution would be have an iterator that generates rows and then simply "merge" these rows together:

```py
def rows(initial_value=0, nb_rows=5, row_increment=1):
    for index, value in enumerate(range(initial_value, nb_rows * row_increment, row_increment)):
        yield f"{index}: {(value, value + row_increment)}"
```

Then:

```py
>>> print(',\n'.join(rows(nb_rows=3)))
0: (0, 1),
1: (1, 2),
2: (2, 3)
```